# Recreating kivy app with scrollview to be used as screen with screenmanager

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I've been trying to use scrollview in a screen, that will be used as part of an app and I managed to find the following code that creates an app with scrollview. But I'm not able to change it into screen class.
Here is the python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ScrollButton(Button):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        super(TestApp, self).build()
        container = self.root.ids.container
        for i in range(30):
            container.add_widget(ScrollButton(text=str(i)))
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 600, 320
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 10
                spacing: 10
                height: self.minimum_height
                size_hint: None, None
                do_scroll_x: False
                id: container

<ScrollButton>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 600, 40
```

I would appreciate if anybody could show how to do it/give me some directions on how to change this to fit my purpose. Any alternative way of doing this is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people recommend making the ScreenManager in the build method in the python file instead, here's how to do that:

**Python**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_file("styling.kv")


class ScrollButton(Button):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):

    def on_kv_post(self, instance):
        container = self.ids['container']
        for i in range(30):
            container.add_widget(ScrollButton(text=str(i)))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen())
        return sm
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**Kivy**

```
<ScrollButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 600, 40


<MainScreen>:
    name: 'MainScreen'

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 600, 320
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            height: self.minimum_height
            size_hint: None, None
            do_scroll_x: False
            id: container
```

**Changes made**

1. ScreenManager made in .py instead of .kv
2. Created Screen class in .py, so we can use python methods from the Screen
3. Widget adding moved to the Screen's class, using on_kv_post (this method is fired only one time when the Screen is ready)
4. Made the screen a template class instead of an object in .kv which the Screen in the python file uses to make the final Screen

PS: *This is how it's **usually** done*

Comment: Thanks for the clear illustration. If there are 2+ screens then how do you access them from TestApp - say MainScreen is 'home' screen and SecondScreen etc. are the others ?

Comment: u create their instance and add to the sm, `sm.add_widget(MenuScreen())`, then if u have one more, just repeat, `sm.add_widget(SecondScreen())`

Comment: Thanks but not what I meant. I'll post as separate SO question and let you know when it is up.